# Automatic Text in Excel

Tags: excel, email

I have an Excel sheet of leads that has store names and email and some other pertinent information. I have one master sheet of stores and emails and different sheets with lead info. for each week.

I want to have the store emails automatically populate the email field when a store is entered in the leads sheets. So it would need to search the list of store names in the master email sheet and then when it finds it, put the email associated with that store in the email column.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You can use the excel's function LOOKUP. This function has 3 parameters:

- Valor_proc : The value that you want to find, in your case the name of the store;
- Vector_proc : The vector which has the values that you will search, the column or line with the store name;
- Vector_result : The vector with the results that the function will retrieve, in your case the column or the line with the store's emails.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.

It worked when there was only one store and email in the list. But I added a second one and it's associating the second store email with the first store name. What am I doing wrong? Should I be using VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP?

Comment: You could use VLOOKUP if you have the data organized in columns and HLOOKUP if its in lines. They are generalizations of LOOKUP, and assuming that you have your data organized in columns I will explain  how to use VLOOKUP. It has 4 fields: -Value:value which you want to search for;-Table_array:table where the data is, and this selection must start on the column where the name of the store is;-Index_number:index of the column where the data that you want is, in your case if the email column is immediately after the name then its a 2;-Not_exact_match:use a 1 to retrieve the correct value.